# Java script in model view of web application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am reading a tutorial on a web application. This is one of the simple UI java script called home.js. This syntax looks very new to me, and even horrible. It looks like two parameters are defined for a function (no function name?). What is text! The parameter of applyTemplate seems to be "$(this.el),HomeTemplate,{}".

What does this whole thing do? Why is it so messy?

```
/**
 * The About view
 */
define([
'utilities',
'text!../../../../templates/desktop/home.html'
], function (utilities, HomeTemplate) {

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render:function () {
        utilities.applyTemplate($(this.el),HomeTemplate,{});
        return this;
    }
});

return HomeView;
});
```

Comment: You have to learn some basic JavaScript and read about AMD. After that it will not be that messy anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [defining a module with some dependencies](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep). The `text!` means that you have [some textual (non-javascript) dependencies](https://github.com/requirejs/text).

If you're new in the javascript world, it's maybe a little premature to use backbone and requirejs; try to familiarize yourself with the syntax and best practice. You can have a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

Comment: Pure JavaScript looks better for me, though I am not very familiar. But the thing above looks really weird, which is very different from most other programming languages. I think it's really hard understand, and ever harder to debug, should any problem occur, or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @martin This is not true. Why would AngularJS(Google) and other frameworks even exist? It's not hard to debug(breakpoints in dev tools) and it's very easy to maintain(modules). Your problem is lack of JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: @GuyT, What's relationship between AngularJS and Backbone.js and require.js? Thanks.

Comment: @martin When you're used to it, it's not that weird ;) I agree this look messy at first glance.

Comment: @martin AngularJS and Backbone are both JavaScript frameworks mostly used to build SPAs. It's a good practice to use RequireJS for modular loading.